# Tags difference and commit message

Tags: svn, changelog

I am new to SVN. I need to get the report for comparing two tags and along with the commit message.

ie I need whole path of the file and commit message as report.

Please let me know is there any svn command or any script will solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you follow the common conventions regarding folders organisation in your repository (`trunk/branch/tags`) and that your tags are both created from the trunk, you can do the following:

First, if you want the changelog between 2 tags, you will first need to find the revisions corresponding to those tags.
This can be done for `Tag1` for instance using the command:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy https://repoAddress/tags/Tag1
```

The resulting output would be something like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r106 | myName | 2012-06-06 17:15:34 +0200 (mer., 06 juin 2012) | 1 line

Commit message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From there you can find that the corresponding revision is `106`.
Doing the same for the other tag will give you the second revision (say `258`).

Then you can have your complete changelog by executing the following command:

```
svn log --verbose -r258:106 https://repoAddress/trunk
```

Comment: That's not XML. Requesting XML output might make sense if you want to process it further, but for human consumption, the regular textual format is what you want.

Comment: You can diff between two tags directly; just give the tag URLs as arguments to `svn diff`. Or do you want just the commit messages?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for noticing the typo, it's fixed now. And does `svn log` accepts 2 tags as arguments also?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows you can use PowerShell to do all sorts of neat tricks with system data. I wrote a small suite of tools to analyze Subversion meta-data of the sort you are looking for. Here is an example doing exactly what you requested: collect the paths and the log messages for all the files touched between two tag names. You do not have to go cross-reference the tags to revision numbers--it does that for you automatically.

```
Get-SvnLog -ByFile `
    -TagPath file:///C:/usr/svn/cleancode/tags `
    -RevisionRange "Release_1_1_04:Release_1_2_01" |
Select Revision, Path, Msg |
Format-List
```

Here is a portion of the output.

```
Revision : 1255
Path     : /trunk/devel/cleancode-support/sourceXml/translate.xsl
Msg      : Improved XSLT with variable for 'newline'.

Revision : 1256
Path     : /trunk/devel/cleancode-support/sourceXml/translate.xsl
Msg      : Updated google analytics tracking code.

Revision : 1257
Path     : /trunk/devel/cleancode-support/build.xml
Msg      : Updated google analytics tracking code for language APIs: java, perl, powershell, and c#.

Revision : 1257
Path     : /trunk/devel/cleancode-support/analytics-files.txt
Msg      : Updated google analytics tracking code for language APIs: java, perl, powershell, and c#.
```

Note that you might have many files in one commit. The use of the `-ByFile` parameter says to explicitly enumerate each file separately (thereby seeing duplicate log messages). If you omit the `-ByFile` parameter--and select `Paths` instead of `Path` in the property list--you get this more concise listing:

```
Revision : 1255
Paths    : <paths><path action="M" kind="">/trunk/devel/cleancode-support/sourceXml/translate.xsl</path></paths>
msg      : Improved XSLT with variable for 'newline'.

Revision : 1256
Paths    : <paths><path action="M" kind="">/trunk/devel/cleancode-support/sourceXml/translate.xsl</path></paths>
msg      : Updated google analytics tracking code.

Revision : 1257
Paths    : <paths><path action="M" kind="">/trunk/devel/cleancode-support/build.xml</path><path action="A" 
           kind="">/trunk/devel/cleancode-support/analytics-files.txt</path><path action="M" 
           kind="">/trunk/devel/dotnet/Projects/CleanCode/SandCastle/CleanCode.shfbproj</path><path action="M" 
           kind="">/trunk/devel/powershell/scripts/psdoc_template.html</path></paths>
msg      : Updated google analytics tracking code for language APIs: java, perl, powershell, and c#.
```

You can see the API for Get-SvnLog in my [open source bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html). Open the PowerShell "book" and go to SvnTools. Download the code [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html).